# Simulating Linux-like admin privilege enabling in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, admin, sudo, user-management

In Linux, when we execute a script/application/command line which needs **sudo**, it ask for the **password** even current logged account has sudo privileges.

In Windows, if admin user account is logged in, all it asks for executing the app is clicking a button. For implementing this kind of procedure in Windows 10, I created 2 different accounts that one is **normal** and other is with **admin** privileges. So far it satisfies the needs when we execute a privilege needed process on normal account, it asks for the **password** of admin account. But problem starts when switching between user files (Interraction between Normal user desktop and admin user application doesn't work).

Basically, I would like to create a sudo alike user in Windows 10. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to simulate or stimulate linux?

Comment: Simulate. Edited header.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows , you can run an application as admin , even though logged in as normal user

Do a right click on application -> compatiblity -> (change settings for all users)